# split one row to two rows while inserting in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have one raw table where i want to split one row to two rows based on the category.
My code is working as per expectation right now. but i want remove while loop for doing this task.

I am not able to do it using bulk insertion my code does not work for more records, as this operation i am performing while excel upload.

```
CREATE TABLE #RAW_TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),FIELD1 VARCHAR(100),CATEGORY VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #RAW_TABLE (FIELD1,CATEGORY) VALUES ('DATA','SINGLE')
INSERT INTO #RAW_TABLE (FIELD1,CATEGORY) VALUES ('DATA','SINGLE')
INSERT INTO #RAW_TABLE (FIELD1,CATEGORY) VALUES ('DATA','SPLIT')
INSERT INTO #RAW_TABLE (FIELD1,CATEGORY) VALUES ('DATA','SINGLE')
INSERT INTO #RAW_TABLE (FIELD1,CATEGORY) VALUES ('DATA','SINGLE')

CREATE TABLE #PROCESSED_TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),FIELD1 VARCHAR(100),CATEGORY VARCHAR(100))

Declare @Int int,@Field1 Varchar(100),@Category Varchar(100)
WHILE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #RAW_TABLE) > 0)
BEGIN   
    PRINT ''
    SELECT top 1 @Int = ID,@Field1 = FIELD1,@Category = CATEGORY FROM #RAW_TABLE 

    if(@Category = 'SPLIT')
    begin   
        insert into #PROCESSED_TABLE (FIELD1,CATEGORY) values (@Field1 + '-1',@Category)
        insert into #PROCESSED_TABLE (FIELD1,CATEGORY) values (@Field1 + '-2',@Category)
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into #PROCESSED_TABLE (FIELD1,CATEGORY) Values (@Field1,@Category)
    end

    Delete from #RAW_TABLE Where id = @Int 
END


Select * From #PROCESSED_TABLE
```

Output :-
[image]

Comment: You can use CURSOR instead of while loop

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with a query.  No looping is necessary:

```
insert into #processed_table (field1, category)
    select (case when rt.category = 'SPLIT'
                 then concat(rt.field1, '-', v.n)
                 else rt.field1
            end), rt.category
    from #raw_table rt cross join
         (values (1), (2)) v(n)
    where v.n = 1 or rt.category = 'SPLIT';
```

Comment: Sir, Main problem of mine is I want to concatenate -1 & -2 with that data.

Comment: @HardikParmar That should be a trivial change for someone with years of tsql experience. You need a case expression to supply the appropriate value for the category column - give it a try. You will find this easier to understand / visualize if you just focus on the select statement and include the column v.n in the column list of that select statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can Put `UNION ALL` and INSERT Twice for SPLIT records.

```
insert into #PROCESSED_TABLE (FIELD1,CATEGORY) 
SELECT concat('DATA','-1') AS FIELD1, category  FROM #RAW_TABLE as T1
WHERE T1.CATEGORY = 'SPLIT'
UNION ALL
SELECT concat('DATA','-2') AS FIELD1, category  FROM #RAW_TABLE as T1
WHERE T1.CATEGORY = 'SPLIT'
```